# distinct values from the yii mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

How could I get the distinct values from the mongodb collection in yii.
Is it same as that in sql ie can I use distinct(fieldname) in yii.

Answer (score 0):

In Yii I believe you would have to access the mongodb object directly and work on it using the `distinct()` command:

```
Yii::app()->mongodb->command(array("distinct" => "your_field", "key" => "your_key"))
```

This will not return an AR format of the results since MongoDBs distinct doesn't quite work like SQLs however you could emulate something of SQLs distinct with the aggregation framework with most likely `$group` on your field.

There might be a way of doing this with whatever plugin you are using in Yii however we have no idea other than the fact that you are using Yii...